# XML Configuration File is gone

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a problem with IntelliJ IDE, because when I want to add XML Configuration File, I can't. There is no options where you can choose from the list.

[image: FILE]

How can fix this "problem"? Is it something wrong with plugins?

[functions what i do not see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvMAG.png)

Comment: go to application directory and then cxreate your XML it's not a big deal

Comment: What XML config file? Do you mean the *.iml file for your IntelliJ module? Or are you referring to some other config file?

Comment: I think about that. I do not have this function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate entry for the xml file. You may just create it as a plain text giving it .xml extension.

Common xml configuration files (like application server-specific descriptors or Spring xml config) IDE adds automatically with corresponding actions, e.g. if this is Spring-based project:
[image]

or when you want to add web deployment or Java EE Application Server-specific deployment descriptor:
[image]

You may also create your own [file template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html) for xml file in [File and Code Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-file-and-code-templates.html) page of the Settings/Preferences dialog.